# Users can change html code to delete what they want

Tags: jquery, html

I have this javascript to remove a certain image from the website:

```
$(function() {
  $(document.body).on("click", ".deleteImg", function() {
    var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
    var parentImgBox = $(this).closest("start");
    var dataString = 'id='+item_id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/removeitemajax.php", <--THIS FILE WILL REMOVE IMAGE FROM DATABASE
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data){
            if (data == 0) {
                alert('Error');
            } else {
                if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
                    parentImgBox.remove();
                }
            }
        }  
    });
  return false;
  });
});
```

This is what I use in my file.php:

```
... PHP code reading through the database for images. Query varaible: $queries['blablabla']...

echo'
<start>
<div class="headPhotoGalleryIconBox">
    <img src="'.$queries['name'].'"></img>
    <div class="large-6 other_columns">
        <a id="'.$queries['id'].'" class="deleteImg"><i class="step fi-page-delete size-36"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
</start>';
```

As you may already see, this script depends on the `item_id` of the image.

My problem is that users/visitors can edit the website's sourcecode to change the id of the `<a>` and remove an optional content with that id.

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to verify that the user has permission to delete the image before you actually delete the image. This must be done on the server side, using whatever authentication you are currently using.

Never, never, NEVER rely on the accuracy of user input to perform actions like this. ALWAYS recheck to make sure the user has permission to do something like this before doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control what HTTP requests come into your server.

You have to perform some kind of authentication and authorization process.

Identify who the request is coming from (e.g. with a login system) then check they are authorized to delete whatever it is they are trying to delete (e.g. check that the user id in the "owned_by" column matches the user id of the authenticated user).

Comment: Aha, yes that will do it. But, it is messy.

Can I do it in another way instead of using "id" in the phpfile?

Comment: yes you can create a Guid instead of id, but ... you really should do server side check.

Comment: @Bart — Um, what? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Mussemou — It isn't "messy". It is the standard way to do pretty much anything sensitive on the web.

Comment: My commend was in response to @Mussemou comment. GUID serves the same purpose of the FREAKENGINEER MD5 response (but needs to be saved on DB). insead of using id = 1 you end up using some low collision string like d93bd3a4-a093-4ce7-9035-f6f742832320. Still, not recommended since Quentin or Ben Dyer solution is the way to go.